# Image resize depending on orientation?

Tags: images

is there an option or a plugin that resizes an image depending on it's orientation?

Reason for this question:

Im building an image grid and it would look even better when all images would have the same width.

Comment: +1 Very basic question but [seems that has never been asked here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bimage+%2Bresize+%2Borientation), kudos for that! ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was also really impressed that nobody had asked anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the images to be the same width but varying heights (ie not 300 x 300 but 300 x anything) then in settings -> media add 9999 to the height of whichever image size you want to use.

You can also define your own custom thumbnail using the same principle: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

[EDIT] As @brasofilo suggests, you can also use 0.

Comment: Zero has the same effect as 9999. Who knows if someday we'll have cameras with one trillion mega-pixels, maybe around WordPress 10 :)